# NSSegmentedControl programmatically highlight segment

Tags: cocoa, osx-yosemite, nssegmentedcontrol, nscontrol

I have a `NSSegmentedControl` in which, upon user's click, some conditions should be met before the action is sent to its target.

Till now i managed to do this, by overriding the `-mouseDown` event handler and invoking the segmentedControl's `[super mouseDown]` handler only after successfully checking my conditions.
Only one problem. The user doesn't have any visual clue that a segment has been clicked until `[super mouseDown]` is invoked.

So the question is: is there a way to set an "highlighted" state programmatically (more or less like "`setHighlighted`" for `NSButtons`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can deselect the clicked segment in the action method.
You could detour through an additional action method

```
- (IBAction)toggleSegments:(id)sender
{
    NSSegmentedControl *segmentedControl = sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegment;

    if (! conditionsAreMet) {
        [segmentedControl setSelected:NO forSegment:selectedSegment];

        return;
    }

    [NSApp sendAction:@selector(reallyToggleSegments:) to:nil from:sender];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre. Your solution is better then nothing, but there's still some point. For example, during the test, the segment will be displayed as *selected*, suggesting that the choice has been accepted. I was looking for a way to only *highlight* the segment, not select it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of not invoking `-[NSSegmentedControl mouseDown]` when conditions are not met, you need to not invoke `-[NSSegmentedCell stopTracking:at:inView:mouseIsUp:]`.

Here’s an NSSegmentedControl subclass I wrote that uses a delegate to conditionally enable segment selection: https://gist.github.com/michal-tomlein/39171668c580ac0d497d

You’ll see that the segment is highlighted while you hold down the mouse button, but is then unhighlighted and selection remains unchanged if you return `NO` from the delegate method.

If you use it from Interface Builder, don’t forget to set both the view class (`MTSegmentedControl`) and the cell class (`MTSegmentedCell`).

Comment: Thank you Michal. I'll give your code a try and let you know if it solves my problem.